# How to describe to stay updated about current trends

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to describe a futuristic goal about learning and stay updated on current trends in the field of drug regulations.

> Stay updated about the current trends related to Drugs regulatory requirements

is there a better way to describe my goal??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler and less wordy alternatives might be:

> Stay (or **keep**) abreast of drugs regulations
>   or
>   Stay (or **keep**) up with drugs regulations
>   or
>   Stay up with/abreast of trends in drugs regulations

There is no obvious reason to capitalize **Drugs**.

The word **current** is unnecessary in this context as it is implied.

**Regulatory requirements** seems to be a long-winded way of saying **regulations**.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stay+abreast+of